# Prove divergence of sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$a_n=1+n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$

So the above sequence is obviously not convergent because of the sine, but how could one prove this? Thanks for any pointers.

Tom

Comment: Try to write down the first several term and you will see that it is not bounded. Thus it does not converge.

Comment: Is this sufficient proof though?

Comment: Yes because convergent sequence must be bounded.

Comment: What about sequences that become bounded after a great number of terms?

Comment: Those sequences are then bounded....  For example, $\{1, 2, 3, \cdots, 100000^{10000} , 0,0,0,\cdots \}$ is bounded sequence.

Comment: Well, show the definition of converge fails.  Show that for any $x \in R$ any $\epsilon > 0$ and any $M \in R$ you can find an $n > R$ where $|x - a_n| > \epsilon$.  Or perhaps more simply, {$a_{4n + 1}$} = {$1 + (4n+1)$} is a divergent sub sequence.  (By John Ma's comment {$1 + (4n + 1)$} is not bounded so...  Or by my comment, for any x and any epsilon we can find large enough n such that |x - (4n + 2)| > epsilon for all n large enough.)

Comment: @John Ma but wouldn't that mean writing down the first several term which is not bounded is not enough to show the divergence?

Comment: @croo1 . Writing down first several terms can't show that it is bounded, but can help the OP "see that it is unbounded".

Comment: I see the point. It is indeed a good problem solving technique.

Comment: Aren't those equivalent statements?

Comment: You have to prove it is unbounded.  That for any M there is an |a_n| > M.  You can't "notice" a sequence is unbounded just be looking at a  finite number of terms.  But I think the comment was suppose to mean if you look and a_1 = 2, a_5 = 6, a_9 = 10, a_4k+1 = 4k + 2, one should notice a pattern that very clearly indicates that the sequence is unbounded and how to demonstrate it.

Comment: They are subtly different.  A simpler example is a_n = 10^n.  If you write down the first few terms:  1, 10, 100, 1000, 10,000....  You can "see" that it is unbounded (obviously) but  simply writing them down doesn't show or prove anything.  You have to prove that for any M there exist an a_n where |a_n| > M.  Which you can do by pointing out if n > $\log_{10}$ M then a_n > M.

Comment: These are quite different , @t.kelso . In doing mathematics we first try to look for pattern, then we try to show that formally. These two are quite different technique. Try to write down the first several term, take a look carefully at the term $\sin (n\pi/2)$. Observe that there is indeed periodic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequence $a_n=1+n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$ has a subsequence 
$$b_0=a_1,\ b_1=a_5,\ b_2=a_9,\ \ldots,\ b_k=a_{4k+1},\ \ldots$$
of a form $b_k = 4k+2$ which is divergent. Hence sequence $\{a_n\}$ is divergent.

**UPD:**
$$b_k = a_{4k+1} = 1 + (4k+1)\sin\left(\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{2}\right)= 
1 + (4k+1)\sin\left(2k\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 
$$
$$
= 1 + (4k+1)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 1 + 4k+1 = 4k+2
$$

Comment: Looks nice, but what were the steps required to find the subsequence? It looks nothing alike.

Comment: Basically whenever $n$ is of the form $4k+1$ the $\sin$ expression goes to $1$ so that you just get $n+1$ as that element of the sequence.

Comment: @t.kelso, added details

Comment: I see. Is this a general rule or a theorem or just intuitive thinking? Or a combination of both?

Comment: sin(n pi/2) = 1 if n = 1,5,9,13.  sin(n pi/2) = 0 if n = 2,4,6,8.  sin(n pi/2) = -1 if n = 3,7,11,15...  a_n = 1 + n if n = 1,5,9,13.  a_n = 1 if n = 2,4,6,8.  a_n = 1 -n if n = 3,7,11, 15.

Comment: @t.kelso, the fact that every subsequence of a convergent sequence is convergent is a theorem (general rule). In this case you look at $\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$ and see that every 4-th time it hits $1$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks you guys.

Answer (score -1):

We know that a sequence if diverging to $\infty$ iff $\forall G \in \mathbb{R}$, no matter how large it is, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_k>G \; \forall k \geq n$. Well, we can easily find any odd number $>m$ and then the property will hold for some of the terms (all the terms $a_k, k>G, k \equiv 1 \; (\mathrm{mod}\;2))$. So, we have a diverging subsequence. But, we have another subsequence $\{1,1,1,...\}$ which converges to $1$. So, the sequence is neither converging nor diverging to $\infty$, it's infinitely oscillating.

BUT, if we consider divergence as the negation of convergence, it's definitely diverging as it has a diverging subsequence.